# Formatar valor CustomFormat em LiveBinding

Tags: delphi

Estou com problemas ao tentar usar a propriedade `CustomFormat` do *LiveBinding*, estou tentando formatar um valor obtido do banco de dados para o formato de número com separador de milhar.

Estou usando:

```
Format('%d',[Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma').Text])
```

Porem é retornado o seguinte erro:

> Invalid or incompatible with argument

Answer (score 2):

Você está passando uma *String* para ser formatada para numérico é isso mesmo?  Não seria assim:

```
Format('%d',[Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma').AsInteger])
```

Comment: Vou testar e reporto.

Comment: Claudio não funcionou, vou dar mais detalhes o valor é retornado de um servidor datasnap utilizando a técnica de reflection usando JSON o valor no banco de dados SQL é um decimal (similar ao money). Eu recebo os dados em um memtable e faço o binding em um listview.

Comment: Desculpe a demora na resposta, se ele é um decimal tente assim :  Format('%10.2f',[Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma').AsFloat])

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver passando um valor com [ponto flutuante](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante), não use o formato `%d`, ele é usado para *inteiros*, use `%m` para valores monetários ou `%n` para valores com ponto flutuante. Seu código pode ficar assim:

```
Format('%n', [Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma').AsFloat]);
```

### Atualização

Segundo a página [Default LiveBindings Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Default_LiveBindings_Methods) o funcionamento da função [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.Format) é um pouco diferente ao usar [LiveBindings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Custom_Format_and_Parse_Expressions_in_LiveBindings), ao invés de especificar um *array* de argumentos `[.., ...]`, adiciona-se como parâmetro.

Por exemplo, o uso normal de [`SysUtils.Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.Format) geralmente é assim:

```
Format('%d %d', [1, 2])
```

Em [LiveBindings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Custom_Format_and_Parse_Expressions_in_LiveBindings) deve-se usar:

```
Format('%d %d', 1, 2)
```

Seguindo esse raciocínio você pode usar:

```
Format('%n', Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma').AsFloat);
```

Comment: Fiz o teste não funciona o app simplesmente fecha, fiz o debug e verifiquei que o erro é o mesmo que informei no início do post, EConvertError  Invalid or incompatible with argument. Creio eu que a sintaxe do format quando usado no livebinding deve ser outra.

Comment: Tentei de tudo que é jeito sempre dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: @edmjunio Será que esse valor `Self.Owner.FieldByName('soma')` não é de um outro tipo? uma *string* talvez? tente trocar o formato de `%n` para `%s` e  `.AsFloat` para `.Text` ou `.AsString` (não sei se existe).

Comment: Tentei de tudo quanto é jeito inclusive existe um chamado sobre isso aqui no site, fiz testes basendo nele mas não consegui.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801484/using-format-in-a-livebindings-customformat

Comment: Caso você tenha oportunidade poderia tentar reproduzir o erro, basta usar um componente Prototypebindsource e um listview. Fazer o bind Incluir no Prototypebindsource um item do tipo currency e na propriedade customformat tentar formatar com separador decimal e de milhar, no caso o %n.

Comment: @edmjunio Andei lendo sobre isso e realmente parece que `%n` não vai surtir efeito e `%s` é reservado. Consegui reproduzir o erro. Então na propriedade `CustomFormat` usei `Format('%%.2f', %s)` e `UpperCase(%s)` *ambas* não lançaram erro. Dê uma olhada nesse [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Custom_Format_and_Parse_Expressions_in_LiveBindings#Binding_Expressions), ali fala sobre essas expressões no *Binding*. Esse [artigo](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/96985) pode ser muito útil também.

Comment: Já tinha lido estes dois artigos. O primeiro foi o que eu estava me baseando até o momento. Já o segundo eu não queria ter que chegar nesse nivel de ter qie criar uma classe registrar os metodos etc etc. Mas acho que não vai ter como escapar.

Comment: Complicado. Um [`TFloatField`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TFloatField) da classe [`TNumericField`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TNumericField) pode resolver esse problema usando a propriedade [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) com o formato `#.00`. :)

Comment: Eu recebo o valor via json datasnap populando um memtable o binding não é feito direto no field

Comment: @edmjunio Nesse caso eu não tenho nada em mente do que pode ser feito. Talvez o conteúdo do segundo link possa ser uma alternativa plausível. =)

Comment: Vou implementar amanhã a recomendação do segundo link e reporto